# React app on IIS - client side routes not working

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, webpack, web-config, iis-7.5

We are starting a new react app. When we try to deploy it on IIS, IIS messes up the client side routes.

If you access the app and then browse, all routes work fine. But when you try to access it with a URL, it says 404 not found.

How do we fix this ?

We are using react-router-dom version 6 with BrowserRouter. The web.config looks right to me. The web config rewrite rules look like:

```
            <rule name="CANappsv3 /portal" stopProcessing="true">
                <match ignoreCase="true" url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^\/canappsv3(\/.*)?"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/project/canappsv3/index.html{C:1}" appendQueryString="false"/>
            </rule>
```

Note: This project was initialized using create-react-app .

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using IIS node?

Comment: I think so, there already is a react app deployed on the server that works fine.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules FRT should tell you why.

Comment: Do you have any other error messages besides 404 not found?